# Can someone help me identify this onomatopoeia?

Tags: translation

[image: Picture]

I'm drawing onomatopoeia from JoJo's Bizarre Adventure for the fun of it, but I would at least like to know the meaning (and romaji) of what i'm trying to draw. I've been trying to identify this but these katakana only look slightly similar to some I see on Wikipedia. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

(please note that I do not have very much knowledge of Japanese)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ガン
>   ガン
>   ガン...

Pronounced as "gan gan gan..."

It's an onomatopoeia often used for the sound of hitting something hard.

Answer (score 0):

ガン、ガン、ガン、ガン... Gan,gan,gan... Interesting, metal fist hitting sound.

Comment: Please explain how this answer differs from the accepted one.